# Cast inherited variable to subclass

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, casting, subclass

I have two closely knit cluster of classes. For the sake of explanation, lets call one the `view` and the other the `template`. The `template` tells the `view` how to look. I have a base `view` and base `template` class and a number of paired subclasses of them.

So, like so:

**Base Classes**

BaseTemplate <-> BaseView

**Subclasses**

TemplateA <-> ViewA
TemplateB <-> ViewB
TemplateC <-> ViewC
TemplateD <-> ViewD

The `view`s (Even the base `view`) each have a `template`, of the corresponding type, as a variable. ***How can I cast, for example, the variable of `BaseTemplate`, declared in `BaseView`, to `TemplateB`, declared in `ViewB`?*** I would like to be able to set variable information in the `BaseTemplate`, rather than having to set generic information in all the template subclasses.

Comment: Typically you would use generics to express this, though probably only in one direction.

Comment: @PaulBellora I'm not quite sure what you mean by "express".

Comment: I mean declaring `BaseView<T extends BaseTemplate>`, `ViewA extends BaseView<TemplateA>`, etc. You mentioned not wanting to do this, so I didn't post it as an answer. I'm interested in why though.

Comment: @PaulBellora Maybe my word choices were wrong. I only meant that I wanted to utilize subclassing so that I didn't have to set variables common to each subclass inside of each subclass. I'm not familiar with the syntax you have in the comment, but if that will help to solve my problem, then I'm all eyes (since ears aren't really applicable).

Comment: See my answer and let me know if you need anything clarified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you could use [generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) to address this issue. For example:

```
public abstract class BaseView<T extends BaseTemplate> {

    private final T template;

    protected BaseView(T template) {
        this.template = template;
    }

    //common view methods operating using T etc.
}

public final class ViewA extends BaseView<TemplateA> {

    public ViewA() {
        super(new TemplateA()); //or wherever templates come from
    }

    // ViewA specific stuff
}
```

Comment: So, if I had a local private reference of that `new TemplateA()` named templateA in `ViewA`, any values I set in template would be set in templateA, as well? Also, does final just mean that it can only be set once? I had thought it meant it had to be set inline.

Comment: I apologize for the last bit. A simple google was all I needed. (`A final variable can only be initialized once, either via an initializer or an assignment statement.`)

Comment: I apologize further, but this syntax just clicked. The <> Is just stating that there is a `Class` that can be subclassed, but it hasn't explicitly stated how just yet. `T` is essentially an empty subclass that has every component of the superclass and `<TemplateA>` is where it finally explicitly states and "converts"/casts the variable `template` to the subclass type `TemplateA`. Thank you!

Comment: @RileyE No problem - glad I could help! That link in the answer goes to the generics article of the Java Tutorials, which is a good intro. Beyond that refer to Angelika Langer's awesome generics FAQ for more in depth explanations: http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html

Comment: Oh. I didn't even notice the link. I just, sort of, stared at your answer for a little while and thought about it. It clicked and it's a rather "cool" way to go about it. I will definitely give those a read, though.